# gradle with maven submodule

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle

There is any way to build gradle project with maven submodule ? I created a project in gradle but at now I must add module (that module used a maven) I don't have any idea how to used this. There is any good way?

I will be very gratefull for any suggestions.

Comment: Do You have any example?

Comment: You can add the other modules as dependencies.

Comment: Why mix build technologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either convert the Maven project to Gradle (`gradle init` is a good start) and turn the Gradle build into a multi-project build, or publish the Maven build's artifact to the local or a remote Maven repository, and configure the Gradle build to consume it from there (or the other way around).

Answer (score 0):

Create a `build.gradle(.kts)` that wraps the Maven project in its root directory:

```kotlin
val build = task<Exec>("build") {
    commandLine("mvn", "package")
}

val default by configurations.creating {
    isCanBeConsumed = true
    isCanBeResolved = false
}

artifacts {
    add(default.name, File("$projectDir/target/<name of the jar>.jar")) {
        builtBy(build)
    }
}
```

You can then depend on it like this:

```kotlin
implementation(project(":<path to the module>", "default"))
```