# Unable to use Gradle and Maven projects in Intellij same workspace

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea

I recently changed my main module's (X) build tool into gradle. previously it was maven build tool.

API interface related module (Y) is still in maven.
Y module implementation is done in the X module.

For development I'm using Intellij idea 2020.1 version.
I imported both the projects into Intellij, but X module(under gradle) does not resolve Y module (under maven) project source...
It always refers the jar file.

What is the correct way to import these modules?

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755229/gradle-with-maven-submodule#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=Either%20convert%20the%20Maven%20project,or%20the%20other%20way%20around).)?

Comment: @TomasZezula yes... we manage to resolve artifacts maven to gradle and gradle to maven as well. Our problem is in the IDE level.

Comment: Why don't you convert it into a gradle multi-module project then?

Comment: @YAS_Bangamuwage Try to close the IDE, remove **.idea, .gradle** folders, and all **.iml** files from the project directory and create a [project from existing sources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html#create-from-sources). Contact JetBrains support team via [Submit Request](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=6673) form if the problem remains.